# US based broker for European citizens

Tags: online-brokerage

I have US stocks, and I need to transfer them to a new broker (long story). I am a non-US citizen, I am a European citizen.

Is there a list of online brokers that I can do this with? I am unsure if I need a US-based broker that lets Europeans use their platform, or if a non-US-based online broker would also work?

eToro does not, apparently, let me transfer stocks into their system.

The total value of the stocks in in the 6 digit range, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe "Interactive Brokers"?

Comment: anything other than them?

Comment: I'm a US citizen in the US, so don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Interactive Brokers. I have opened an account with them while in the UK quite easily and I think that is the case for all of EU countries. Their platform is geared towards professional traders so it's not the easiest to use.

You can then transfer your positions (search Position Transfers on their website).
https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/index.php?f=40930&p=transfer

I suggest you call them up and confirm.

Degiro is another platform you can try and it's easier to use. They also can help you transfer your stocks, although that might take longer than with IB, because they are not US based.

https://www.degiro.co.uk/helpcenter/faq/portfolio-transfer/1067